# Toggle (create / destroy) connection between two records in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models. User(email, name, etc.), Hobby(name) and Interest which connects these 2 (user_id, hobby_id). In /interests I have a table of hobbies of currently logged in user. How do I create a button to toggle (create and destroy) connection between the user and a hobby?

Here's my attempt:

```
<% @interest = Interest.new(hobby_id: hobby.id, user_id: @user.id) %> 
<%= link_to 'Create', new_interest_path, method: :get, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

And then in new.html.erb

```
<p>UID: <%= @interest.user_id %></p>
<p>HID: <%= @interest.hobby_id %></p>
```

But surely that doesn't work.

I suppose Rails makes a new instance of @interest every time I make request but how can I overcome this?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear right now. Take your time to flesh it out. By the way, you don't have to redirect to `interests/new` to create your interest. You can do it from anywhere with a `form`. In your interests, you can create a form with hidden fields and show only the submit button. Clicking that will create a new `Interest`

Comment: I'll rewrite my question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question, you want to link to a new interest if the user does not have one, and you want to link to the destroy path when the user does have an interest.

So in your controller, you can use `find_or_initialize_by` to fetch a users interest or initialize a new one

`@interest = @user.interests.find_or_initialize_by(hobby_id: hobby.id)`

then in your view, detect whether your user had an interest, or whether we initialized a new one. Then display the appropriate link

```
# check if `@interest` is a db record
<% if @interest.persisted? %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', interest_path, method: :delete, class "..." %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Create', new_interest_path, class "..." %>
<% end %>
```

---

EDIT:

If you want a button to create an interest with one click, you'll need to provide all the parameters you need in the action. There are several ways to do this. you can accomplish this a couple of ways

Using a restful route can be rather verbose here as you have 3 levels of nesting. using a route that looks like

`users/:user_id/hobbies/:hobby_id/interests`

You can then submit a link (or build a form) to this route

`link_to user_hobby_interests_path([@user.id, hobby.id]), method: :post`

or if you want to retain your `/interests` route, you'd need to build a form with the necessary parameters

```
form_for @interest do |f|
  hidden_field_tag 'interest[user_id]', @user.id
  hidden_field_tag 'interest[hobby_id]', hobby.id
  submit_tag 'Create'
end
```

Comment: What I meant to do was to link to a create action so that there are no more steps than just clicking a "Create" button. Looks like my question wasn't clear